# Hi, I am getting an error when try to connect PHP to Mongo?

Tags: windows, mongodb, apache, xampp

I am using XAMPP control panel on windows.

> Error : The message is Class 'Mongo' not found in
>   `C:\xampp\htdocs\ResearchLab1\index.php` on line 14

Other people have asked this question, but I am confused on how to add the `extension=mongo.so` to  `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is [mongo installed](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows)?

If yes then is it in the path?(Just try using MongoDB from the command prompt, i.e. type `mongo` in cmd)

If not then [add the location to Path](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath).

**If you are able to [connect to mongoDB through cmd but not via php](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows), then you probably missed an installation step:**

- open the php.ini file
- Add `extension=php_mongo.dll` in it
- restart apache

You may add `extension=mongo.so` or any extension similarly.

*The `php.ini` is usually found in `C:/xampp/php/php.ini`*

Comment: Yes, mongo is installed  and running . What is the php.ini file ? How do I add the extension.  This is my first time ever using PHP  and mongo

Comment: @Mila Add `extension=mongo.so` or whichever extension you require in the `php.ini` file.